# Is there a way to move the scope of a Mercurial repo up one folder?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I've been using a lovely mercurial repo for a while now, but have recently realized that I really should have created the original repo one level higher in the file structure, as there are files up there that I also want to be version-controlled. Is there a way to "promote" a Mercurial repo up one level so that it also tracks files contained in that folder?

So, the current structure is:

```
-superFolder (not under VC)
    -someFolder (not under VC)
    -someFolder (repo root, under VC)
        -subFolder (under VC)
```

I want:

```
-superFolder (repo root, under VC)
    -someFolder (under VC)
    -someFolder (under VC)
        -subFolder (under VC)
```

I can always just create a new repo, but I'd like to retain my old deltas...

(bonus points if you know how to do it in MacHg, but command-line is also great)

Comment: Is it inside another repo? Are you moving one folder or the whole repo?

Comment: editing my question, hopefully it's more clear now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we imagine you created it like:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir superFolder     
cd superFolder 
mkdir someFolder1
touch someFolder1/file
hg init someFolder2
cd someFolder2
mkdir subFolder
touch subFolder/file
hg add subFolder/file
hg commit -m subFolder
```

hg status -A:

```
C subFolder/file
```

we can move it like:

```
mv ../someFolder1 . # Move the uncontrolled directory in
hg add someFolder1/ # Add uncontrolled directory
mkdir someFolder2 # Re-create *this* directory inside the root.
hg mv subFolder someFolder2 # Move sub-directory of old root to new subdirectory of root
hg commit -m 'Change repo level' # Commit
```

hg status -A:

```
C someFolder1/file
C someFolder2/subFolder/file
```

```
cd ../..
mv superFolder superFolder_old # Move old unmanaged top-level out of way
mv superFolder_old/someFolder2 superFolder # Move root to new name
rmdir superFolder_old # Remove old top-level
```

As you can see, it requires some finagling.  But this preserves history, unlike drharris's solution, which rewrites every commit with a new id.  It depends whether you actually care about the current commit ids (does anyone have them?).  If not, his is easier.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably check out the [Convert Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap) with the `--filemap` option. To do this, you're effectively creating a new repository. Note that this will invalidate any clones that are out there, so use wisely.

You could also do this by treating your existing repository as a subrepo of a new repository under superFolder. Basically, you create a new repo at the level you desire, but exclude the directory of your existing repo. Then, add your existing repo as a subrepo of the new repository. I've never tried this, but I think it would work in theory.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not nested and you want to move the entire repo, just move it (using mv or a GUI, your choice) and everything will stay A-OK unless you have shell scripts or something that depend on the old location, in which case you'd have to update those to reflect the new location.

If you move it to a folder and the root folder name changes, I'm not sure how this should affect remotes, but you should be okay.